# Negative values in the Kullback-Leibler Divergence

Tags: probability-theory

I'm trying to calculate the Kullback-Leibler Divergence via:

$$ KLD = \sum_i P(i) \times \log_2 \frac{P(i)}{Q(i)}$$

My results seem to make sense. For example I get a value 0 if p and q are the same distributions. However, I sometimes get negative values as well. Is it possible to get negative values for KLD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, [no](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kullback%E2%80%93Leibler_divergence#Properties) ${{{{}}}}{{{{{}}}}}$